# ionic 3 android apk stuck on splash screen but running good on browser

Tags: ionic3

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 8.0.0 browser 6.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v10.15.3
npm               : 6.4.1 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
```

this my ionic setup my android apk stuck on splash screen

Comment: is app working properly on emulator ?

Comment: post the logcat message with your query

Comment: my ionic 3 android app is stuck in splash screen and i am not getting any error but my app running on browser well please help

Comment: no only on browser i did not run on emulater

Comment: try to run on emulator and if the issue persist than get the log

Answer (score 0):

first try to inspect your app on Chrome to show what is the problem
and you can change typescript version to 2.6.2 , i thing this should work